Getting data at a specific lat/lon point on a curvilinear grid
I'm working with HRRR data, which is in a lambert conic conformal projection. The specifications for the projection are
projection = ccrs.LambertConformal(
    central_longitude = -97.5,
    central_latitude = 38.5,
    standard_parallels = (38.5,38.5),
    cutoff = 0)

The data is currently loaded as an xarray dataset:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (hybrid: 50, y: 1059, x: 1799)
Coordinates:
    time        datetime64[ns] ...
    step        timedelta64[ns] ...
  * hybrid      (hybrid) float64 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 ... 47.0 48.0 49.0 50.0
    latitude    (y, x) float64 ...
    longitude   (y, x) float64 ...
    valid_time  datetime64[ns] ...
Dimensions without coordinates: y, x
Data variables: (12/17)
    pres        (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    clwmr       (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    unknown     (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    rwmr        (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    snmr        (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    grle        (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    ...          ...
    q           (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    u           (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    v           (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    w           (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    tke         (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    mdens       (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...

I only need data for a specific point, say (39.969, -72.717). geocat.comp.rcm2points used to work for this, but it has been deprecated since 2023. How do I go about this using Python?

As it is mentioned in the geocat-comp documentation, try installing the geocat-f2py package and import it as geocat.f2py.rcm2points. Maybe you will find this issue also helpful: https://github.com/NCAR/geocat-comp/issues/199
